# What will Mason's workshop upgrade into?

Tags: anno-online

I suddenly found that I can upgrade my Mason's Workshop.

What will be the result of this upgrade?

Normally I'd just upgrade, but it costs rubies (for which you need real money).

It seems really lame that upgrading a building like this would require real money.

Although it's not really necessary, because it's not hard to get plenty of stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading a Masons Workshop reduces the cycle time to produce 1 stone. It doubles the production.

[image]

Comment: I tried it, think it doubled production.

Comment: @MrFox yep updated the answer as well